# What does int type signifies in setProperty(String name, String value, int type) method?

Tags: java

The setProperty() method sets the specified single-value property to the specified value. If the property does not yet exist, it is created. It takes in 3 parameters,

- name - the name of the property to be set.
- value - a String object.
- type - the type of the property.

and returns the Property object set, or null if this method was used to remove a property (by setting its value to null).

Source: [docs.adobe.com](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

Why the type is 'int' here? What does it signifies? If I want to set a property named 'x' to value 'true' of type 'boolean', how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you look at the other variants of setProperty, you'll see they supply the type as BINARY, DECIMAL, BOOLEAN etc.   So I infer 'type' is one of those.

Comment: I need to add a new property of type boolean. But on doing so I'm getting error by the IDE as the type of third parameter is expected to be int. But yeah you're right in this regard. But how to work around this, the int type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these constants:

```
STRING 
BINARY 
LONG 
DOUBLE 
DECIMAL 
DATE 
BOOLEAN 
NAME 
PATH 
REFERENCE 
WEAKREFERENCE 
URI
```

[Defined here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/PropertyType.html) as javax.jcr.PropertyType.

Comment: What values can be used to initialize public static final int BOOLEAN? Does setting BOOLEAN = 0, initializes it to false. How does that work?

Comment: *You* don't initialize anything. These are numbers provided for you to use.  Your type argument should be written as ```javax.jcr.PropertyType.BOOLEAN```, or if you import javax.jcr.PropertyType, then as ```PropertyType.BOOLEAN```.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided states the following:

*type - the type of the property.*

Comment: But have you noticed it's int type in the method definition.

Comment: I don't know how to code in Adobe, but I can read from the link you've posted. Seriously though. Why did you ask this question? You've provided yourself with a link that clearly shows the answer to your question. Is there another question you are hiding?

Comment: I need to add a new property of type boolean. But on doing so I'm getting error by the IDE as the type of third parameter is expected to be int.

Comment: another-dave has answered your hidden question.